# How to check if all characters in a file is present in a specific encoding?

Tags: encoding

I do have a UTF-8 file that I would like to convert to ISO 8859-9 and CP1254 (Turkish encodings) respectively. However I am unable to save the files in these encodings (I've tried various software). I suspect that in those files there are characters which are not present in these encodings (although visually everything checks out). How can I check that the characters inside these files are fine?

If I need to write a script or something like that, which path should I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to convert every char from utf-8 file to ISO 8859-9 and CP1254. If there is error or "empty" result(according to library encoding documentation) this char is absent.

Comment: How to do that the easiest way? I've tried lots of converters online and editor software for the conversion, they gave an error.

Comment: you should write script in any language you are familiar with

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it. I just listed all the unique characters in the file, and apparently a Cyrillic letter made its way into the file somehow. All okay now! Thanks anyway.